# What TOC module would work for a mixed Panelized setup?

Tags: panels

I have gone through the "[comparison of TOC modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2278811)" severally, but haven't managed to get something that works. So Ill just ask for those that might be in the know, I use panels, for about seven different content types. The fields inside of some of the content types include a horrible field type called [Multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield), which seems to be giving me more grief than anticipated.

My question: 
Is there a way to render Table of contents using views, and generating all the needed formatting and linking? Alternatively, is there a known TOC module that works with Panels, and Multifiels / large text field / leaflet maps content? I just want to pick all H2 tags in a panelized page and generate a toc at the top.

Comment: Still missing details. Drupal version? Which other modules are in the way? Panelized? Does it mean you use Panelizer too? Or only Panels? How do use Panels? By default it can use the node object or you can add field by field. "Something that works" is not really specific. We don't know what "works" for you and when and why. And what does it has to do with Panels that it won't? Panels alone don't modify the node object.

Comment: My pardon. I have custom content types that have text area fields, and Multifield fields with data. The same have Maps that I generate using entity reference and leaflet & views to generate content panes that are laid out. Everything is put together using drupal panels (not using panelizer) and a page would then have a combination of all these fields.

Comment: Running Drupal 7.38 with the latest versions of panels. My challenge with the table of content modules tried so far, (toc filter, jquery table of contents, simple toc, is that they all seem to have issues working with Panels, or Multifield.